# Updating a line chart with a new line for each ClickData word i press

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Im making a code that shows the frequency of word use over time in Plotly Dash. Right now the code will show the graph for 1 clickData word which comes a graph above it. I would like to be able to select and deselect more than 1 word so they can be compared directly with each word having a different color line in the line chart.

Code right now:

```py
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='word-plot', component_property='figure'),
    Input('word-cloud', 'clickData'),
    Input(component_id='frequencyoptions', component_property='value'))
def display_word_plot(clickData,frequencychoice):
    x = [i for i in dashtext.wordcountbyyear("songs/").keys()]
    y = [1 for i in range(len(dashtext.wordcountbyyear("songs/").keys()))]
    if clickData != None:
        clicked_word = clickData['points'][0]['text']
        wordtable=dashtext.wordcountbyyear("songs/")
        if frequencychoice=="Relative frequencies":
            wordtable=dashtext.relativefrequencies(wordtable)
        y = dashtext.clickedworddata(wordtable, clicked_word)
    return px.line(x=x,
                  y=y,
                  color=
                  labels={'x': 'Year','y':'Frequency'},
                  height=400,
                  template=ourtemplate)
```

The wordcountbyyear function just makes a dictionary where the keys are years and the values are dictionaries with all the words used in that year as keys and their frequencies as values. I assume i gotta save the clickData words as a list somehow? But whatever I tried, failed. Any ideas?

Below is a picture of how it looks right now and a picture of how im picturing it (ish):
[image]
[image]